# White Div in the center of the page on transparent div

Tags: asp.net, css, html

I am trying to display a small white div on a semi transparent div (which is 100% of page and opacity of 0.6)

Divs:

```
<div id="confirmDialogSingle" class="Loading" runat="server" visible="false">
<div id="msgBox" class="loadingImg">
<br /> You already have a request on the chosen date. Are you sure you want to submit this request?<br /><br />
<asp:Button ID="BtnConfirmSingle" runat="server" Text="Yes"  Width="60px" onclick="BtnConfirmSingle_Click" />&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="BtnNo" runat="server" Text="Cancel" onclick="BtnNo_Click" />
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.Loading
{
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    top:0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    background: white;
    opacity:0.6;
    z-index:9999;
    transition: width 2s; -moz-transition: width 2s;/* Firefox 4 */ -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */ -o-transition: width 2s; /* Opera */

}

.loadingImg
{
    opacity: 1;
    margin: auto;
    width: 700px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    border:1px solid #d9a0e2;
}
```

The problem is the small div (.loadingImg) is not being displayed in the center of the screen (have also tried top 50% and left 50%) and its background is still being displayed transparent instead of white!

Comment: It seems to horizontally align center for me. Are you talking about vertically center align? Because that's more difficult.

Comment: Yes I want it in the center of the screen thus horizontally and vertically aligned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.Loading {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%; height:100%; 
    top:0; left:0;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
    z-index:9999;
    transition: width 2s; -moz-transition: width 2s;/* Firefox 4 */ -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */ -o-transition: width 2s; /* Opera */ }

.loadingImg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; margin-top:-85px;
    left:50%; margin-left:-360px;
    width:700px; height:150px;
    opacity: 1;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    border: 1px solid #d9a0e2;
}
```

Alternatively you could use a semi-transparent png image as the background image on the .Loading div

Comment: Div is not appearing in the center of the screen alright, however the smaller div (loadingImg) is still being displayed semi transparent like the first div (0.6 opacity) :S

Comment: I've edited my answer for the semi-transparency. It's because you'd set opacity on the parent div, which sets all of it's children with the same transparency. You need to just set the background color as semi-transparent, not the opacity of it's content. That can be achieved with rgba backgrounds or transparent png backgrounds.

Answer (score 0):

Set **margin-left** and **margin-top** to place the div at center. Also you are setting background of both div as white. Please set background of first div as transparent.
eg:

```
margin-left: 20%;
margin-top: 20%;
```

Comment: You are wrong in both cases. using margins like this will not perfectly align the div to center for all screen sizes. Also, the background div needs to be semi transparent, not fully transparent, so opacity is being used

Comment: What @Coop said as removing the background of first div will render it completely transparent.

Comment: Please have a look into this:http://designshack.net/articles/css/how-to-center-anything-with-css/ .Also one suggestion is you can set the background of first div as "gray" and then set its opacity, it will looking good.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should help you get the second div in the screen center.

```
<div id="confirmDialogSingle" class="Loading" runat="server" visible="false">
<table style="height:100%;" align="center">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="msgBox" class="loadingImg">
            <br /> You already have a request on the chosen date. Are you sure you want to submit this request?<br /><br />
            <asp:Button ID="BtnConfirmSingle" runat="server" Text="Yes"  Width="60px" onclick="BtnConfirmSingle_Click" />&nbsp;
            <asp:Button ID="BtnNo" runat="server" Text="Cancel" onclick="BtnNo_Click" />
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

As for the opacity issue. The first div, You want to change the opacity of the background color as opposed to the actual opacity. Because the actual opacity would affect child controls as well.

```
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
```

Add the above for the top div after removing the opacity:1;